# Does Codex Explain the COBOL code to natural language ( English)

Tags: openais

I found below info in the Azure site.

That is for Explain the Program Code to natural language ( English).

Codex's ability to create and understand code allows us to use it to perform tasks like explaining what the code in a file does. One way to accomplish this is by putting a comment after a function that starts with "This function" or "This application is." Codex will usually interpret this as the start of an explanation and complete the rest of the text.

Does Codex Explain the COBOL code to natural language ( English)

If yes, how to call the Cobol code in CodeX?